# Why have error when i change localhost to my host on the server?

Tags: java, mysql

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Connect {
     Connection con=null;

        public static Connection ConnectDB(){
             try{

          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://cybersolutionstoreco.ipagemysql.com:3306/java?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8","myuser","mypassword");
         //System.out.println("Connect Success");
          return con;

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
    }      
}
}
```

this code can work on my machine if i change url to "localhost:3306/java?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8". i don't know why it shown error like below. please help me.

> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>   due to underlying exception:
>
> ```
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
>
> java.net.ConnectException
> MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect
>
> STACKTRACE:
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
>   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>   at myfirstproject.Connect.ConnectDB(Connect.java:29)
>   at myfirstproject.Login.txtpasswordKeyPressed(Login.java:108)
>   at myfirstproject.Login.access$200(Login.java:13)
>   at myfirstproject.Login$3.keyPressed(Login.java:87)
>   at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6493)
>   at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
>   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6312)
>   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>   at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4762)
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>
>
> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
>
>
> Last packet sent to the server was 4 ms ago.
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at myfirstproject.Login.txtpasswordKeyPressed(Login.java:109)
>   at myfirstproject.Login.access$200(Login.java:13)
>   at myfirstproject.Login$3.keyPressed(Login.java:87)
>   at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6493)
>   at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
>   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6312)
>   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>   at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4762)
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
> ```

Comment: Most probably mysql is binded only to `localhost:3306` not to `*:3306`

Comment: *"Connection refused"* ... what is unclear about that? Check if your server listens for incoming message and check the connection?

Comment: so how can to solved this problem?

Comment: By default, remote connections (i.e. connections from anything else than `localhost`) are disabled on MySQL for security reasons. [Configure your MySQL](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) so that it allows remote connections.

Comment: See also [Troubleshooting Problems Connecting to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html) in the MySQL manual.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple solutions regarding your problem:

1. Is there a running instance of MySQL on your machine?
2. If there is, is the port you are using correct?
3. Have you tried just using `localhost:3306` without the parameters?

If the connection was working before there seems to be a problem regarding your machine and not your code. The code you have given looks fine to me.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: when i'm use localhost:3306 is working normally but when i upload my database to the server and i want to connect to the server it show error above. i don't know of this error. i test my server already, everything is ok.